# Protobuf - different naming of parameters in serialization & desirialization

Tags: java, serialization, protocol-buffers, naming

I'm using protobufs to represent some objects for serialization purposes. I have a client and a server that sends him a msg.
Is it possible to change the names of the parameters as long as I keep the IDs?

That is -

The client has (in it's jar) - `message Example { optional int64 a = 1;}`

And the server has (in it's jar) - `message Example { optional int64 b = 1;}`

Will this work (Serialization/Deserialization)?
(I want to make sure before I make the naming change)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are using the binary format (generally the default), yes - this should be fine; the binary protocol **never includes names** - it only ever involves field numbers. As such, any names are entirely local to the serailization / deserialization code, where it maps `1` to/from `a` or `b`.